# Wix Edit Control white on white with no border

Tags: wix, windows-installer

```
<UI>
    <Dialog Id="GetUserSecretDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Vendor Customer Secret">
        <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install" Hidden="yes">
            <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
            <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
            <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
            <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
            <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
            <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>
            <Condition Action="show">ALLUSERS</Condition>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="UserSecret" Type="Edit" X="188" Y="202" Width="124" Height="18" Indirect="no" Property="CUSTOMERSECRET" />

        <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Customer Secret" />
    </Dialog>
</UI>
```

The Edit control is invisible - white on white with no border.  I tried Sunken.  I tried HasBorder.  (HasBorder is not a valid property).  This is basically a copy of the WelcomeDlg.wxs from the Wix source that was lightly modified.

Answer (score 0):

This was a stacking problem.  The Bitmap control is almost the same size as the dialog.  Maybe the Wix folks were just being sloppy.  So the fix is to move the Bitmap way up to the top of the source file so that the controls further down the source file get stacked on top of it.

I moved the Bitmap to the top of the Dialog element.  If the bitmap was sized appropriately - I'm blaming you Wix source files... then this wouldn't be necessary.

```
<Fragment>
  <Property Id="CUSTOMERSECRET" Value="C:\Heska XML" Secure="yes"/>

    <UI>
        <Dialog Id="GetUserSecretDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Vendor Customer Secret">
            <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
            <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install" Hidden="yes">
                <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
                <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>
                <Condition Action="show">ALLUSERS</Condition>
            </Control>

            <Control Id="UserSecret" Type="Edit" X="188" Y="202" Width="124" Height="18" Indirect="no" Property="CUSTOMERSECRET" />
                ...
```

Comment: I was a little surprised to discover that the order of the controls in the MSI database matters.  It is generally a bad idea to assume that the order you get things out of a database is the same as the order you put them in.  But I'm new to Wix and MSI databases are strange in many ways.